# DNS.GetHostEntry - why does it require fiddling with hosts file?

Tags: networking, dns, proxy, domain-name, hosts-file

I have a Windows app where the following line of C# code gets invoked

```
IPHostEntry connected = Dns.GetHostEntry("www.somedomain.com");
```

It works as it should in 99% of organizations (i.e. domain name resolves to an IP address automatically), only in the 1% of organizations it throws an exception "No such host is known".

Using a Browser to navigate to www.somedomain.com works with no issues. Yet the C# line fails with said exception.

To get around this, we had to manually edit the local hosts file on the user's PC to declare the domain-ip mapping. Can someone explain why is this required? (but not in 99% of cases).

P.S. Really a networking question, i know! just looking for a (plausible) explanation.

Comment: Did `Dns.GetHostEntry("somedomain.com");` work on this 1% of machines? I mean did it resolve to somehting, or did you also got an error as with `www.` perfixed?